# Replace div parameter with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the word "/settings" in data-notification_uri parameter

```
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
```

I tried without success :

```
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('/settings', '');
});
```

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You just need to take the replaced value and put it back in the original string. Also you need to use $(this) when using jQuery methods:

```js
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-notification_uri', $(this).attr('data-notification_uri').replace('/settings', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Working perfectly ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct properties should make this work. Since it's not a `href` but a `data` property.

Using Vanilla JS and `dataset`.

```js
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function(){

    this.dataset["notification_uri"] = this.dataset["notification_uri"].replace('/settings', '');
    console.log(this.dataset["notification_uri"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
```

Using a jQuery solution:

```js
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function(){

    $(this).data("notification_uri", $(this).data("notification_uri").replace('/settings', ''));
    console.log($(this).data("notification_uri"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="um-notification-ajax" data-notification_uri="http://website.com/settings/stack/">TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function(){
    $(this).data('notification_uri', $(this).data('notification_uri'). replace('/settings', ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it Attribute, here is pure js:

```
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')
    [0].setAttribute('data-notification_uri',
    'http://website.com/stack/')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to replace `href` instead of `data-notification_uri`.

This should work:

```
$('.um-notification-ajax').each(function(i, notification){
  var uri = $(notification).attr('data-notification_uri').replace('/settings', '')
  $(notification).attr('data-notification_uri', uri)
})
```